# JAX - Problem in differentiating of function

Tags: python, numpy, montecarlo, jax

I am trying to perform a Montecarlo Simulation on a call and after that compute in Python its first derivative with respect to the underlying asset, but it still does not works

```
from jax import random
from jax import jit, grad, vmap
import jax.numpy as jnp

xi = jnp.linspace(1,1.2,5)
def Simulation(xi):
    K,T,number_sim,sigma,r,q = 1.,1.,100,0.4,0,0
    S = jnp.broadcast_to(xi,(number_sim,len(xi))).T

    mean = -.5 * sigma * sigma * T
    volatility = sigma*jnp.sqrt(T)
    r_numb = random.PRNGKey(10)
    BM = mean + volatility * random.normal(r_numb, shape=(number_sim,))

    product = S*jnp.exp(BM)

    payoff = jnp.maximum(product-K,0)

    result = jnp.average(payoff, axis=1)*jnp.exp(-q*T)

    return result

first_derivative = vmap(grad(Simulation))(xi)
```

I do not know if the way that is implemented the algorithm is the best one to compute the derivative using "AD method"; this algorithm works in this way:

- *S* = Simulate a matrix containing all the underlying; for each row I have each underlying generated with the "xi = jnp.linspace", and inside each row of the matrix I have the same value for a number of times equal to "number_sim"
- *product* = After generating the BM ( vector containing normal number ) I need to multiply each element of *BM* (with exp) with each element of each row of *S*

**So this is a short explanation of the algorithm, I really appreciate any kind of advice or tips to manage this problem, and compute the derivative with AD method!
Thanks in advance**

Comment: Can you edit your question to give more detail about what your expected output is? Gradients are computed with respect to scalars, and it seems that you want the gradient with respect to a vector. Are you actually interested in a jacobian, or an element-wise scalar gradient?

Comment: Hi @jakevdp , thanks for the answer. I need the first derivative of a call option with respect to a set of underlying asset "xi", so my output should be a vector, containing all the derivatives.. Maybe yes, I have developed the code wrongly with respect to a scalar.. If you need more information please tell me! :)

Comment: I edited the title and tags to mention JAX again. It seems strange to ask a question specific to JAX, get an answer specific to JAX, and only after that to remove mentions of JAX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that your function maps a vector *Rᴺ→Rᴺ*. There are two notions of a derivative that make sense in this case: an elementwise derivative (which in JAX you can compute by composing `jax.vmap` and `jax.grad`). This will return a derivative vector of length *N*, where element *i* contains the derivative of the *i*th output with respect to the *i*th input.

Alternatively, you can compute the jacobian matrix (using `jax.jacobian`) which will return a shape `[N, N]` matrix, where element *i,j* contains the derivative of the *i*th output with respect to the *j*th input.

The issue you're having is that your function is written assuming a vector input (you ask for the length of `xi`), which implies you're interested in the jacobian, but you are asking for the elementwise derivative, which requires a scalar-valued function.

So you have two possible ways of solving this, depending on what derivative you're interested in. If you're interested in the jacobian, you can use the function as written and use the `jax.jacobian` transform:

```python
from jax import jacobian
print(jacobian(Simulation)(xi))
# [[0.6528027 0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
#  [0.        0.6819291 0.        0.        0.       ]
#  [0.        0.        0.7003516 0.        0.       ]
#  [0.        0.        0.        0.7181915 0.       ]
#  [0.        0.        0.        0.        0.7608434]]
```

Alternatively, if you're interested in the elementwise gradient, you can rewrite your function to be compatible with scalar inputs, and use vmap of grad as you did in your example. Only two lines need to be changed:

```python
def Simulation_scalar(xi):
    K,T,number_sim,sigma,r,q = 1.,1.,100,0.4,0,0

    # S = jnp.broadcast_to(xi,(number_sim,len(xi))).T
    S = jnp.broadcast_to(xi,(number_sim,) + xi.shape).T

    mean = -.5 * sigma * sigma * T
    volatility = sigma*jnp.sqrt(T)
    r_numb = random.PRNGKey(10)
    BM = mean + volatility * random.normal(r_numb, shape=(number_sim,))

    product = S*jnp.exp(BM)

    payoff = jnp.maximum(product-K,0)

    # result = jnp.average(payoff, axis=1)*jnp.exp(-q*T)
    result = jnp.average(payoff, axis=-1)*jnp.exp(-q*T)

    return result

print(vmap(grad(Simulation_scalar))(xi))
# [0.6528027 0.6819291 0.7003516 0.7181915 0.7608434]
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much!!! Just another little (maybe stupid) question: why did I get the following result : "[0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0]" with the second derivative, calculated with this command? --> print(vmap(grad(grad(Simulation_scalar)))(xi))

Comment: Your function is linear with respect to its inputs, so the second derivative is zero.

Comment: Have you some idea/tips about the second derivatives? @jakevdp

Comment: I'm not sure what tips you're looking for: the second derivative of your function is zero, and JAX is correctly computing that.

Comment: Ok I agree with you that the derivative is zero, but with an analytical formula (instead of montecarlo) the second derivative exist, and I am looking forward also with respect to a tips to be able to compute it.. Tell me if I am not so much clear :) @jakevdp

Comment: If you're asking how to change your model from a linear to a nonlinear one, that seems far too open-ended for a StackOverflow comment thread.

Comment: hi @jakevdp, if you have time, can you help me with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68908160/error-message-in-python-with-differentiation thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sure. In the future, please add the `jax` tag to questions about JAX, that way I'll likely see them.