# Error message in Python with differentiation

Tags: python, numpy, error-handling, jax

I am computing these derivatives using the Montecarlo approach for a generic call option. I am interested in this combined derivative (with respect to both S and Sigma). Doing this with the algorithmic differentiation, I get an error that can be seen at the end of the page. What could be a possible solution? Just to explain something regarding the code, I am going to attach the formula used to compute the "X" in the code below:

[image]

```
from jax import jit, grad, vmap
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import random
Underlying_asset = jnp.linspace(1.1,1.4,100)
volatilities = jnp.linspace(0.5,0.6,100)
def second_derivative_mc(S,vol):
    N = 100
    j,T,q,r,k = 10000,1.,0,0,1.
    S0 = jnp.array([S]).T #(Nx1) vector underlying asset
    C = jnp.identity(N)*vol    #matrix of volatilities with 0 outside diagonal 
    e = jnp.array([jnp.full(j,1.)])#(1xj) vector of "1"
    Rand = np.random.RandomState()
    Rand.seed(10)
    U= Rand.normal(0,1,(N,j)) #Random number for Brownian Motion
    sigma2 = jnp.array([vol**2]).T #Vector of variance Nx1

    first = jnp.dot(sigma2,e) #First part equation
    second = jnp.dot(C,U)     #Second part equation

    X = -0.5*first+jnp.sqrt(T)*second

    St = jnp.exp(X)*S0

    P = jnp.maximum(St-k,0)
    payoff = jnp.average(P, axis=-1)*jnp.exp(-q*T)
    return payoff 


greek = vmap(grad(grad(second_derivative_mc, argnums=1), argnums=0)(Underlying_asset,volatilities)
```

This is the error message:

```
> UnfilteredStackTrace                      Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-78-0cc1da97ae0c> in <module>()
>      25 
> ---> 26 greek = vmap(grad(grad(second_derivative_mc, argnums=1), argnums=0))(Underlying_asset,volatilities)
> 
> 18 frames UnfilteredStackTrace: TypeError: Gradient only defined for
> scalar-output functions. Output had shape: (100,).
```

The stack trace below excludes JAX-internal frames.
The preceding is the original exception that occurred, unmodified.

---

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jax/_src/api.py in
> _check_scalar(x)
>     894     if isinstance(aval, ShapedArray):
>     895       if aval.shape != ():
> --> 896         raise TypeError(msg(f"had shape: {aval.shape}"))
>     897     else:
>     898       raise TypeError(msg(f"had abstract value {aval}"))

> TypeError: Gradient only defined for scalar-output functions. Output had shape: (100,).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message indicates, gradients can only be computed for functions that return a scalar. Your function returns a vector:

```py
print(len(second_derivative_mc(1.1, 0.5)))
# 100
```

For vector-valued functions, you can compute the jacobian (which is similar to a multi-dimensional gradient). Is this what you had in mind?

```py
from jax import jacobian
greek = vmap(jacobian(jacobian(second_derivative_mc, argnums=1), argnums=0))(Underlying_asset,volatilities)
```

---

Also, this is not what you asked about, but the function above will probably not work as you intend even if you solve the issue in the question. Numpy `RandomState` objects are stateful, and thus will generally not work correctly with jax transforms like `grad`, `jit`, `vmap`, etc., which require side-effect-free code (see [Stateful Computations In JAX](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax-101/07-state.html)). You might try using `jax.random` instead; see [JAX: Random Numbers](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#random-numbers) for more information.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. For vector-valued functions, you can compute the jacobian (which is similar to a multi-dimensional gradient). Is this what you had in mind? --> Yes, it is the point, thanks! Can I ask you one more (last) question? In this situation, the result is an array containing all zero, it is possible with some operation, compute the derivative, with non-zero value?

Comment: If the function has a nonzero gradient, the gradient will be nonzero. An example: `grad(lambda x: x)(0.0)` is nonzero despite the function itself returning zero.

Comment: yes, I agree with you, but in your opinion, is possible to rewrite this function in a way that I am able to compute this combined derivative?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... maybe open another question with more detail?

Comment: yes, maybe is better, I am going to do it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68939327/python-differentiation-with-backward-method-vs-finite-differences thanks in advance :)